# Log4j is not accessible in eclipse

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm new to java. Need to use log4j in the project. I have added the class path for both core and api files of log4j. But when i try to import the file into my project, i'm getting an error saying "The type org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger is not accessible".I Need your help to fix this issue. [image: The error and the classpath screenshots]

Since i'm new to development and IDE. I'm not sure about how to check the IDE settings.

Comment: Nowadays (since Maven was released 20 years ago) we don't download dependencies manually. It doesn't immediately answer your question, but I would advise you to follow a tutorial for setting up a simple Maven or Gradle project; then import that into your IDE. It will save time in the long run. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose a steep slope to learn Java: you have a `module-info.java` module descriptor in it. The Java Platform Module System was introduced in Java 9 (cf. [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-modularity)), but is far from being widespread.

You have two solutions:

- remove the `module-info.java` file from your project,
- or move both libraries to the "Modulepath" and add:

  ```java
  requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
  ```

  to your `module-info.java` file (which is the `log4j-api` module, the `log4j-core` module is runtime-only and you shouldn't access it in code).